# How to convert Scala byte array (UUID) to string within a spark joinWith function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Unable to successful compare these two values in the conditional parameter within `joinWith` . Ive tried casting but got strange errors within my tests.

```
    val finalMinus = minusVideoCall
      .alias("minus_metadata")
      .joinWith(
        finalMinusAirTruth.alias("macs"),
                  // UUID struct<value:binary>                          // String 
$"minus_metadata.event.originalMinusId".cast("string").eqNullSafe($"macs.allIds.minus_id"),
        "left"
      )
```

```
 |-- event: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- originalMinusId: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
```

Comment: What's this UUID in this case. Is it a column? If yes, to which dataframe it belongs to?

Comment: event column with an <struct> list of values. I did a few joins before this but it belongs do a different data frame that needs to be redacted.

Comment: updated with schema